# Angular2 *ngFor with nested ngTemplateOutlet and ngOutletContext with text input

Tags: angular, nested, ngfor

I'm trying to create a List component that wraps items. Its all working really well when the list Items are Objects but I can't get it working when the list Items are strings even when using trackBy index.

calling code:

```
<app-list [list]="_question.options" [title]="'Options'" [columnTemplate]="listBody" (onDelete)="onDeleteOption($event)"
    (onMove)="onMoveOption($event)" (onAdd)="onAddOption()">
</app-list>

<ng-template #listBody let-index="index" let-item="item" let-list="list">
    <td class="vertical-middle">
        <app-input [(ngModel)]="list[index]"></app-input>
    </td>
</ng-template>
```

component code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index; trackBy:trackListBy;">
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="columnTemplate" 
[ngOutletContext]="{item: item, index: i, list: list}"></ng-template>
```

component.ts trackList by:

```
trackListBy(index: number, item: T) {
    return index;
}
```

So the problem is because the items are strings when you start updating the input field the list is re-rendered and focus is lost. From what I've read though the track by should fix this. I tried using trackby without the extra complication of the templates and it does work as expected. Its just not working in this nested scenario. Hopefully there is a work around for them moment I'll just make sure I use Objects.

Here is the correct plunker that hopefully better describes the issue.
https://plnkr.co/edit/3Il1ND?p=preview

Cheers
Rod

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/aOsZow?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to yurzui for that solution. It seems that removing the item from the context and instead only passing the index into the context has resolved the issue.

See plunkers above for more details.

Answer (score 0):

`NgTemplateOutlet` `#ngOutletContext` has been removed as it was deprecated since v4. 
Use `NgTemplateOutlet` `#ngTemplateOutletContext` instead